# My attempt at the "This statement is false" paradox

Tags: propositional-logic, check-my-answer, philosophy

(I haven't read any literature on this paradox nor am I good at formal proofs, so this is just my intuitive thoughts on the paradox.)

If we assume the statement "This statement is false" as a function `f()` on a state machine `M`, where `M` has 2 states `S0` and `S1` representing `false` and `true`, we'd just be evaluating `M.f()` in a certain state. In this case, `M` is cyclic and has no initial or terminal state.

If we initialize with `M(S0)`, the first evaluation will result in `M.f() -> S1`, and vice versa. However, the paradox in question doesn't give an initial state. Therefore, the truthiness of the statement, basically the state of `M` is about as uncertain as Schrödinger's cat - we can't evaluate the state/truthiness of `M` until we've observed the internal state.

However, if we start off with `M(S0)`, evaluating the paradoxical statement would just be like `M.f().get_state()` which would give us `S1`, in which case we do have a definitive answer to the statement.

I think the same logic can be used for any statement (or state machine) without an initial state & a terminal state. If you start with an unknown input, you don't know the output, but if you know the input, evaluating the statement would just give you the result at that 1 state.

Does this work to (somewhat) solve the "paradoxical" aspect of the statement, or do I fundamentally misunderstand the relation between truth and functions?

Comment: Do you have a particular question?  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.  This site format isn't really designed as a blog for posting thoughts, or an open-ended sharing of ideas and request for general feedback.

Comment: Your discussion revolves around a logical function. A function is not a logical statement and has no truth value, full stop. The paradoxical sentence "This statement is false" is vaguely related to the equation $f(x)=x$, which has no solution. Don't be tricked by the quantum computers.

Comment: On another hand, there is no need to "solve" the paradox. This is just an expression to which we can't assign a meaning in the frame of first order logic, just like we can't assign a meaning to $\frac10$ in the frame of algebra. Nobody complains.

Comment: What does it mean that a statement is a function on a state machine? Statements are not defined as functions on state machines so if you want them to be defined that way you'll have to explain it as this is a new invention of yours. (For that matter, what is a function "on" a state machine?) Otherwise it seems more like philosophy than actual mathematics.

Comment: Your argument vaguely resembles Spencer-Brown's [LoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Form) who employed something similar to your oscillating fixed-point free argument of the liar functional form to speculate on inflection-point/consciousness. In CS a dfa automaton itself unambiguously defines the syntactic language acceptance function/program with its potentially arbitrary input sentences which unfortunately doesn't directly assign any truth conditional semantic meaning of the input where symbol grounding mediation is needed. Tarski proved in PA truth cannot be defined by any formula.

Answer (score 1):

The paradox which you seem to be alluding to is often referenced as the [Liar's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) or in another form, [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) which in such form technically speaking is set theoretic. The crux of such a paradox is a statement that seems to produce the following logical form:

**S<sub>1</sub>** If x is true, then x is false.
**S<sub>2</sub>** If x is false, then x is true.

Obviously if you were try to make such an argument on the stand in law, you'd annoy the judge. And if you iterate through the statements, you get a cycle. S<sub>1</sub> implies S<sub>2</sub>, and vice versa. **What should be made of this thinking in the discipline of computer science?**

First, note that two logical statements are atemporal, that is, there is no variable related to time, event, state, etc. If you take truth to be atemporal, then you have a statement that seems neither to be true or false *at the same time* because it obviously IS true and false at the same time. In [truth-conditional semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics), this is a problem because it violates the classical notion of the [principle of bivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence):

> In logic, the semantic principle (or law) of bivalence states that every declarative sentence expressing a proposition (of a theory under inspection) has exactly one truth value, either true or false. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) A logic satisfying this principle is called a two-valued logic[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics) or bivalent logic.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence)... In formal logic, the principle of bivalence becomes a property that a semantics may or may not possess. It is not the same as the law of excluded middle, however, and a semantics may satisfy that law without being bivalent.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox)

The formalism of an execution model of something like the [Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine), is NOT atemporal because Turing defined the model as a sequence of operations through time. In practice, for instance, [state diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram) implicitly presume that transitions of states represent discrete increments of time. So, what should be made of your attempt to conflate the Liar's Paradox, an object of logical study with that of software engineering, an object of computational study?

First, that mathematical logic exists in its most complete form as [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory). Second, that models certainly can have a temporal variable. And lastly, that the paradox itself isn't and cant' be solved (if you continue to accept the principle of bivalence), but that it hints that adding additional temporal variables moves you from a static logical structure of truth, to one in which truth values can be opposed, and that's acceptable. I am wearing my hat. I am not wearing my hat. There is no contradiction (See [Stanford Philosophy's "Dialetheism"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/)).

And yes, this post would be more at home on [PhilSE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) (the average computer scientist gives the philosophical foundations and historical origins of thought of their discipline short shrift), though strictly speaking, **computational theory does examine the nature between functions and truth, since a computer can be modeled as a [Lambda calculus](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), which plays heavily in understanding the Church-Turing thesis. This question is squarely in the philosophy of computer science**, and would be very comfortable in a course that uses [Boolos's Computability and Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521701465). Don't be fooled into thinking that since a function is not a logic statement, the two are unrelated. That would be a sin.

Answer (score 0):

> If we assume the statement "This statement is false" as a function `f()` on a state machine `M`

This is a good example of choosing the wrong concept to formalize something :)

First of all, you really mean a function on the *set of states* of the state machine M. But more importantly, the "state machine" part is really completely irrelevant -- it's just a function on the set of Booleans: `f: Bool -> Bool`. Remember that for state machines it's necessary that they have one transition function *for each alphabet symbol.* Here, there's no input alphabet and only one transition function, so thinking of it as a state machine is likely to overcomplicate things. (It's not incorrect, per se -- you can think of it as a state machine with no input alphabet, or with an input alphabet consisting of a single character, `f` -- but it's not super helpful, either.)

> I think the same logic can be used for any statement (or state machine) without an initial state & a terminal state. If you start with an unknown input, you don't know the output, but if you know the input, evaluating the statement would just give you the result at that 1 state.

I do think you have some insight here! Let me rephrase: you can think of self-referential Boolean statements as functions, `f: Bool -> Bool` (or generalized to multiple inputs: `f: Bool^n -> Bool^n`.) Each time you evaluate the function, it updates the truth value assigned to each input. Then perhaps the meaningful statements are those which are fixed: repeatedly evaluating `f` always leads to a fixpoint (even if you don't know the initial state!). The not-well-defined functions, when iterated, never converge to a fixpoint.
But as the other answer states, this is really a question [for the philosophers and logicians](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

> I have a question about the relation between functions and truth, such as that discussed in the Church-Turing thesis.

This doesn't have much of anything to do with the Church-Turing thesis! Your question, and formalization here, is related to the study of Boolean logic and truth values.